# Is it possible to change the Tab order in a Tab widget?

Tags: google-app-maker

Created a series of tabs layout widget.

How is it possible to change the order the tabs appear on the page from left to right. ie. I want the tabs to appear A, B, C but I added them in the order of A, C, B ?

Is the only solution to remake the tabs? I imagine this is a common problem as new content will be added as the project grows.

(To avoid confusion, I know it is possible to change which tab is 'selected' when the page opens - I am not talking about this.)

Answer (score 0):

In the Property Editor at the bottom of the "Tab Properties" you can choose the position of your selected tab. For exemple one click on the "RIGHT" button will exchange the position of your selected tab with the tab of right

Comment: thanks - can't beleive i missed that - thought it was an alignment setting!!